# How can I debug this Crystal Reports Formula

Tags: sql, debugging, crystal-reports, formula

How can I debug this Crystal Reports Formula?

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global NumberVar lCounter;
Global NumberVar lSoftCR; 
StringVar sRetVal:='';
If RE7CUFlBITON({FinRep.Flags}, 16) then (lSoftCr:=lSoftCr+1; sRetVal:=sRetVal + '#');
sRetVal
```

it highlights RE7CUFlBITON and say it's expecting a number currency amount boolean dat time date-time or string there? i've played around with it for a while and can't figure it out. This was exported from The Raiser's edge supposedly into crystal format but with obvious errors.

Comment: What is the formula supposed to do? RE7CUFlBITON is obviously the error, so what kind of field is {FinRep.Flags} and what kind of data is in it?

Comment: {FinRep.Flags} is supposed to currency

Comment: In your field explorer, right-click on the {FinRep.Flags} field and choose "Browse Data". You should be getting something...

Comment: so it actually referrers to a calculated soft credit field that comes out of the backend of RE

Comment: The question now is, what condition in that field are you looking for that will decide the value of the variables?

Comment: I'm really not sure, my guess is if there is a soft credit or not, and if so the soft credit amount?

Comment: Can you give me a sample value from that field, please?

Answer (score 0):

So the formula is obviously looking for a condition on {FinRep.Flags}. Usually the format of ({FinRep.Flags},x) is looking for something on the x of the field in a string, so in our case it's looking for something on the 16th place of {FinRep.Flags}, but you say {FinRep.Flags} is a currency field, so that wouldn't work. In a string, if the condition is met, then it sets the values for the variables accordingly. 
Can you give us a value sample for {FinRep.Flags}?